# Remove all the String before :

Tags: regex, vb.net

```
"\:(.*)$"
```

Hi all i am using above expression to remove all the string before `:` (colon), but it is giving me all the string before this. how can i do this. Thanks a lot.

My string is:

```
This is text: Hi here we go
```

I am getting: `This is text`

I want :  `Hi here we go`

#### Updated code

```
Sub Main()
    Dim input As String = "This is   text with   : far  too   much  "
    Dim pattern As String = "\:(.*)$"
    Dim replacement As String = " "
    Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
    Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, replacement)

    Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input)
    ' MsgBox("Original String: {0}")
    Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result)
    MsgBox("Original String: {0}")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show your VBA code.

Comment: This is not VBA, this is VB.NET. Please change your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern. This will help you to match string after colon

/*?:(.*)/

or

/: (.+)/

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
Dim pattern As String = "(.*)\:"
' in vb if above one doesn't work, then try this one
' Dim pattern As String = "^(.*)\:"
' also i don't think we need to use any brackets here as well.
```

This regex means, anything before the colon(:), Where you were using anything after the colon(:) in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not dead set on RegEx then you can also use

```
 Dim result As String
 result = Strings.Split(Input, ":", 2)(1)
```

This splits the input into an array with two elements. First element is the text before the first ":", the second element is the text after.